# CS50 Pset1/Cash. While loop doesn't recognize equality

Tags: while-loop, cs50

I'm having some trouble getting a correct solution to pset1/cash. The while loop doesn't seem to recognize when my current "change owed" value is equal to a coin denomination value. Here is my code for 10 cents for example (I've added the constant printing of values to aid in the diagnostic):

```
printf("%f\n", change);
printf("%i\n", coins);

while (change >= 0.100000)
{
    change -= 0.10;
    coins++;
}
printf("%f\n", change);
printf("%i\n", coins);

while (change >= 0.0500000)
{
    change -= 0.05;
    coins++;
}
printf("%f\n", change);
printf("%i\n", coins);
```

And this is the output for those segments:

```
0.200000
16
0.100000
17
0.050000
18
```

So we have .200000 left as change owed and so it correctly detects that this value is >= .100000, subtracts .10 from the current value and adds 1 to the coins counter. But then instead of recognizing that the next current value of .100000 is equal to the .100000 stipulated in the while loop it goes on to the next while loop and correctly detects that indeed .100000 >= .05 and subtracts .05. Why doesn't the while loop recognize that .100000 >= .100000 is True?

I've tried adding and subtracting 0's from the while loop to try to get it recognize that fact.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heed this warning from the spec:

- Beware the inherent imprecision of floating-point values. Recall `floats.c` from class, wherein, if `x` is `2`, and `y` is `10`, `x / y` is not precisely two tenths! And so, before making change, you’ll probably want to convert the user’s inputted dollars to cents (i.e., from a `float` to an `int`) to avoid tiny errors that might otherwise add up!
- Take care to round your cents to the nearest penny, as with `round`, which is declared in `math.h`. For instance, if `dollars` is a `float` with the user’s input (e.g., `0.20`), then code like

  ```
    int cents = round(dollars * 100);
  ```

  will safely convert `0.20` (or even `0.200000002980232238769531250`) to `20`.

Comment: Thank you! I should read the instructions in their entirety.

Comment: The first pset is the best time for that lesson!